# Using pandas for the probability of two nodes to be linked in a network

Tags: python, graph, pandas

**From a network, I want to plot the probability of two nodes to be connected as a function of their distance to each other.**

I have two pandas series, one (`distance`) is the distance between each pair of node and the other (`adjacency`) is filled with zeros and ones and tells if the nodes are connected.

My idea was to use `cut` and `value_counts` to first compute the number of pairs having a distance inside bins, which works fine:

```
factor = pandas.cut(distance, 100)
num_bin = pandas.value_counts(factor)
```

Now if had a vector of the same size of `num_bin` with the number of connected nodes inside each bins, i would have my probability. but how to compute this vector?

My problem is how to know among, lets says the 3 couple of nodes inside the second bin, how many are connected?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reshaping.html?highlight=crosstab#cross-tabulations) for this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

factor = pd.cut(distance, 100)

# the crosstab dataframe with the value counts in each bucket
ct = pd.crosstab(factor, adjacency, margins=True,
                 rownames=['distance'], colnames=['adjacency'])

# from here computing the probability of nodes being adjacent is straightforward
ct['prob'] = np.true_divide(ct[1], ct['All'])
```

Which gives a dataframe of this form:

```
>>> ct

adjacency           0    1  All      prob
distance
(0.00685, 0.107]    7    4   11  0.363636
(0.107, 0.205]      6    9   15  0.600000
(0.205, 0.304]      6    6   12  0.500000
(0.304, 0.403]      5    2    7  0.285714
(0.403, 0.502]      4    6   10  0.600000
(0.502, 0.6]        8    3   11  0.272727
(0.6, 0.699]        6    2    8  0.250000
(0.699, 0.798]      4    6   10  0.600000
(0.798, 0.896]      4    5    9  0.555556
(0.896, 0.995]      5    2    7  0.285714
All                55   45  100  0.450000
```